# MYSQL LEFT JOIN + WHERE clause return rows with NULL result

Tags: mysql

I have a query in MYSQL

```
 SELECT grand.user_id,grand.package_id,MAX(grand.grand_level) AS level,pam.original_title,um.name
    FROM grand_score_master AS grand
    LEFT JOIN package_master AS pam ON pam.id = grand.package_id
    LEFT JOIN user_master AS um ON um.id = grand.user_id
    WHERE grand.package_id='d47kndffqc' AND grand.user_id='CBS_00001'
```

So if the WHERE clause is matched the result is as expected.

But when the WHERE clause is not matched I expect `0 results` but mysql gives me 
[image]

How can I have "0 results" in LEFT JOIN / INNER JOIN.

I will use this query in PHP for AJAX requests.

[image]

Comment: when you left join, you're saying "take all columns from table a, and append relevant columns from table b". Anything that has a `package_id` or `user_id` that matches in that where (but nothing that matches `user_master` or `package_master` will be null.

Comment: Is it empty result set, or you get some rows from database, but all values is null? I propose to you execute same query, but with `*` instead of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ISNULL method for sql amd IFNULL for MySQL.

Eg `ISNULL(grand.user_id,0)` , `IFNULL (grand.user_id,0)`